# How to unbind an event defined by a global function?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have an event binded to a global function (I need it to keep track of the function itself).

e.g.

```
 window['mUpEventHandler'] = function(){
      // ...
 }
```

It's binded to $('body') via

```
 .on('mouseup')
```

Now I know that I can unbind it knowing the name of the handler as in

```
 $('body').off(myHandler) // # myHandler = mUpEventHandler  for example
```

However when defining it globally, I have the function itself but not its name.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you bind using a namespace. Then remove the event based off the namespace?

https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

```
window['mUpEventHandler'] = function () {
  alert('test');
}


$('body').on('mouseup.mUpEventHandler', function () {
  mUpEventHandler()
});


$('button').click(function () {
  $('body').off('.mUpEventHandler');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/5p7t22mh/

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. Is it 100% equivalent to 
$('body').on('mouseup', window['mUpEventHandler']), or is there any difference?

Comment: It is the equivalent besides that fact that it holds a seperate designation in the back workings of jQuery so you can remove the event without removing all mouseup events.

Comment: so I could bind a set of events to the same namespace (mUpEventHandler) even for different events (e.g. using a generic eventHandleNS instead) and put them off with one single instruction?

Comment: Correct. Above i'm shutting off all events with the namespace .mUpEventHandler however if you only wanted to shut off click.mUpEventHandler you could pass .off('click.mUpEventHandler')

Answer (score 0):

In `$('body').off(myHandler)`, `myHandler` is not a "name", it's a variable that references a function.

To unbind an event handler you need a reference to the function. So

```
$('body').off(mUpEventHandler)
// or
$('body').off(window.mUpEventHandler)
```

will work just fine.

Comment: I tried to do so but looks like something is wrong: Uncaught TypeError: (b || "").match is not a function

Comment: I figured out why, off requires also the event name, not only its handler